# analytic continuation of the spectral zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, spectral-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation

The spectral zeta function is defined as:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_{n}^{-s}$$

Where $\lambda_n$ is the real spectrum of $L$ (an elliptic self adjoint operator).

I derived an analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$:

$$ \Psi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\sqrt{n^s}K_1(2\sqrt{n^s})  $$

where $K_1$ is a Bessel function.

Now this form shows up in QFT when computing the one-loop effective action. Essentially you use the spectral zeta function and analytically continue it getting $\Psi(s).$

> I derived the analytic continuation in just one line using my own approach, but I'm wondering what is the usual process to obtain $\Psi(s)$ from $\zeta(s)?$

See this for more: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.7069.pdf.

Comment: What is $\lambda_n$?

Comment: An interesting [document](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/karlsson/spectralzeta.pdf) you have maybe already seen...

Comment: @TymaGaidash it's the real spectrum of $L.$ And $L$ is an elliptic self adjoint operator

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for sharing!

Comment: I see. Also Interesting reputation

Comment: @TymaGaidash What do you mean?